# Can't hide my DIV with JavaScript

Tags: .net, javascript, html

This is my DIV

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <div class="fa_close"><a href="#" onclick="hFa()"><img src="fadead/close1.jpg" /></a></div>
    <h1><i>THIS WEEK'S</i></h1>
    <img src="fadead/special.jpg" alt="special" />
</div>
```

And I am trying to hide it like this but it does not want to work

```
document.getElementById("MyDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the same "id" value? If so, stop doing that.

Comment: Nope, thats the only DIV with that name on the page....

Comment: You may want to use Firebug or the IE8 web tools, to verify that the visibility style has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you provided works fine.  There must be something else interfering.  Test: http://jsbin.com/ilofi

Remember that `document.getElementById("MyDiv")` returns `undefined` if the element hasn't been loaded yet.  Thus, `document.getElementById("MyDiv")` is `undefined` in the following case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById("MyDiv"));
</script>

<div id="MyDiv"></div>
```

But it's the element in the following case:

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById("MyDiv"));
</script>
```

Put scripts as close to the bottom of the page as possible for both this reason and for [performance reasons](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Answer (score 4):

You must make sure that your code runs *after* the browser has actually seen your markup.  If you're trying to hide the element from a `<script>` block in the `<head>`, then the browser will not have seen the element yet so it won't find it.

Move your `<script>` block to the very end of the `<body>` and see what happens!

Answer (score 3):

if you really want to hide something use

```
document.getElementById("MyDiv").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Nope still does not work, maybe because I am trying to hide it inside the HEAD tag?

Comment: so i guess you have written the code to execute in head tag before loading body tag. so make sure your body loads completely by writing the same code at the end of body tag

Comment: @Etienne: When you try to do something from the <head> tag, most of the time, the script runs even before the target element is rendered. This causes the script to cause no effect. Make sure you run it after the rendering is done. If you look at the code I wrote above, it works fine. This is so because, I call it after the target element is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give it a `style` with `display:none`? Since this JavaScript is running in the HEAD, you clearly intend to have it be the starting condition of the DIV, but I can't think of a good reason to do it with JS instead of good old HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the following HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="MyDiv">
    <div class="fa_close"><a href="#" onclick="hFa()"><img src="fadead/close1.jpg" /></a></div>
    <h1><i>THIS WEEK'S</i></h1>
    <img src="fadead/special.jpg" alt="special" />
</div>
<input type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('MyDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden'; "/>
</body>
```

and it is working perfectly on my FF and IE8.

What is the browser you are using? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

you can always can try to use a framework like mootools or jquery
this could help you a lot doing works like a lot more simple

mootools
$("MyDiv").setStyle('display','none'); 
Demos:
http://demos.mootools.net/

JQuery:
$("#MyDiv").hide();
Demo
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

if you want to view more
http://www.ajaxrain.com